# ESLint TableRow is not defined - React in .NET Core project

Tags: reactjs

I created React project in .NET Core and I read this tutorial to learn React:
[ReactJs components](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_components.htm)

In above example table is rendered like this:

```
render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} 
                     data = {person} />)}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }
```

And I get error: TableRow is not defined.
What is TableRow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if you have defined the below component somewhere in your App?

```
class TableRow extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <tr>
            <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
         </tr>
      );
   }
}
```